# Python - how to clear screen when switch is toggled

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Right now, i am trying to make the turtle graphic screen clear and reset everything when i toggle a new algorithm using the tab key. The toggle part works however i am unable to clear the whole screen when i toggle to a new algorithm.


My codes are as shown below:

```
from pynput import keyboard
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, Key, Controller
import keyboard
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, clearscreen, clear
import sys


def lefthand_Algo():
    execfile('...')

def bfs_Algo():
    execfile('...')

# Creates the title
def title():                                              
    t = Turtle()
    t.color('white')
    t.write('Hello, hit tab to start the algorithm!', font=('lemon',20,'normal'), align='center')
    t.hideturtle()

screen = Screen()
clearscreen = clearscreen
clear = clear

screen.bgcolor("black")                                        # Set the background colour
screen.setup(width=0.9, height=0.9)                            # Setup the dimensions of the working window  
title = title()

current_state = bfs_Algo
next_state = lefthand_Algo

switch = False

def toggle():
    global switch
    switch = not switch
    if switch:
        next_state()
    else:
        current_state()

screen.onkeypress(toggle, "Tab")
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

Note: The algorithms are in separate files and this file is just for the toggling between the two files.


How do i clear the screen each time i toggle? Help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you provide full code?

Comment: Have you tried using `turtle.reset`?

Comment: @RhinoRunner Ohh yes, it worked! I kept thinking that it was going to be either clear or clearscreen. Thanks :)

Comment: @StackAsker7 Lol I think `clearscreen` is for pygame!

Answer (score 0):

From @RhinoRunner in the comments:

> Use `turtle.reset()`.